# xcode no matching provisioning profiles found

Tags: xcode, matching, provisioning-profile

I have an Adhoc iOS application that give me a "no matching provisioning profiles found in xcode 6", I have created a Adhoc profile, downloaded it, doubleclicked it and selected a Team under General - Identity. But I then get that message, and try to use the "Fix issue" button does not help. In Build settings - Provisioning Profile - Release I have "Automatic".

Can anyone please help me, I'm totally lost...

Answer (score 12):

Another cause of this nasty little error:

I didn't realise, but your XCode Project has one set of Code-Signing & Provisional Profile settings, but the Targets in your Project have another.

Today, I *had* set the correct Provisioning Profile values in Project, but XCode 6.1 was quoting a *different* Provisioning Profile name in its Build Error of "**The provisioning profile specified in your build settings ("Mikes Provisioning Profile") has an AppID of..**"

So, be careful that you check your settings in *both* places, if XCode quotes a Provisional Profile name which you weren't expecting.

It's amazing that XCode has reached v6.1, and its still as developer-unfriendly as ever.

If anyone needs me, I'll be at the pub...

Answer (score 7):

1. Please install the Distribution Certificate in your Mac
2. Edit your Ad-Hoc Provisioning Profile in Developer account
3. Save the Provisioning Profile
4. Download the Provisioning Profile
5. Double Click to install in your Xcode 6
6. Go to Xcode Preferences, please check whether your developer account is configured or not, if yes please refresh the list, if not please configure your developer account.
7. Clean the project
8. Now check for the Ad-Hoc Provisioning Profile and Distribution certificate in your Build Settings
9. **Important** is by using the Ad-Hoc Provisioning Profile you can not run the app in your device, you need to make an IPA and make a Testflight link and install the app in your device by using the Testflight link

Comment: I also had to re-archive my project

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and did the following to resolve. 
Go to Account section, download all provisioning profiles in account.
Clean and Build again.
Hope this help you.